# PHP Bootstrap Pagination

Tags: php, jquery, pagination

I have a major head ache trying to setup bootstrap PHP pagination with mySQL calls to get COUNT called outside the code in a separate PHP file.

Basically I need three variables currentpage, total (number of items) and number of items per page.   I obtain the currentpage using the following JQuery:

```
    $(".custompages").on("click"," li a", function(){
                $(".flowerloader").show();
                var current = parseInt($(this).attr("id"));
                getPagination(prop_perpage, current);
            });
```

I obtain the total number of items through an ajax call and I define number of items per page as 20.  So I have three variables to pass to my getPagination.php

```
    <?php

     // Retrieve data from POST request 
    if($_POST){
        $current = $_POST['currentpage'];
        $total = $_POST['propertyNumberMax'];
        $propertiesperpage = $_POST['prop_perpage'];

    }
    //stage 1 equations
    $eqx=floor($current/5)*5;
    $eqy=ceil($current/5)*5;
    $eqz=fmod($total, 5);
    if($eqz == 0 && ($eqy!= 5)){ //**edit checked it was not first 5
        $pre = $eqx-5;
    }else{
       $pre = $eqx;
   }

   $html = '<li><a href="#" id="1">First</a></li>';
   // stage 2
    if($current<=5){
       $html = $html . "<li><a href='#' id='1'>&laquo;</a></li>";
   }else if ($current>5){
       $html  = $html . "<li><a href='#' id='".($eqx-4)."'>&laquo;</a></li>";
   }
   // stage 3 a **edit change total to over properties
    if(($total/$propertiesperpage)>= $eqy){  
       $condition = $eqy;
     }
   if(($total/$propertiesperpage) < $eqy){ 
        $condition = $eqx + $eqz + 1; 
    }
    $html2 = $html;

    for ($x = $pre; $x < $condition; $x++) {
        if($current == ($x+1)){
            $insert = 'class="active"';
     }else{
           $insert = '';
}   
//stage 3 b
    $html2 .= '<li '.$insert.'><a href="#" id="'.  
   ($x+1).'">'.$propertiesperpage*$x+1)."-". 
   ($propertiesperpage*$x+$propertiesperpage).'</a></li>';

   }
   $html3 = $html2;
   //stage 4  Problem here
   if($eqy==$total){
        $html3  .= "<li><a href='#' id='". ($eqx+ 1) ."'>&raquo;</a></li>";
   } 
   if($eqy<$total){
        $html3 .= "<li><a href='#' id='". ($eqy + 1) ."'>&raquo;</a></li>";
   }
   if($eqy>$total){
        $html3 .= "<li><a href='#' id='". ($eqx + 1) ."'>&raquo;</a></li>";
   }
   //stage 5
    $html3 .= '<li><a href="#" id="'. floor($total/$propertiesperpage)   
    .'">Last</a></li>';
   echo $html3;
   //}

   ?>
```

The problem with the code is highlighted with "problem here".  I'm getting for 149 properties the following output: 
[image]

When it should stop at 141-160 for 149 properties and the > should except if at end move it 20 properties across.

Can you help, really would appreciate it!